# How to manage memory using classes in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

This is my first time creating an iPhone App and I am having difficulty with the memory management because I have never had to deal with it before.

I have a UITableViewController and it all works fine until I try to scroll down in the simulator.  It crashes saying that it cannot allocate that much memory.  I have narrowed it down to where the crash is occurring:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeue or create a cell
    UITableViewCellStyle style =  UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BaseCell"];
    if (!cell) cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:@"BaseCell"] autorelease];

    NSString* crayon;

    // Retrieve the crayon and its color
    if (aTableView == self.tableView)
    {
        crayon = [[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getName];
    }
    else
    {
        crayon = [FILTEREDKEYS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = crayon;

    if (![crayon hasPrefix:@"White"])
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [self.crayonColors objectForKey:crayon];
    else
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the *getName* method:

```
- (NSString*)getName
{
    return name;
}
```

name is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

Now sectionArray is an NSMutableArray with instances of a class that I created *Term* in it.

*Term* has a method *getName* that returns a NSString*.  The problem seems to be the part of where crayon is being set and *getName* is being called.  I have tried adding **autorelease**, **release**, and other stuff like that but that just causes the entire app to crash before even launching.

Also if I do:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"test"; //crayon;

/*if (![crayon hasPrefix:@"White"])
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [self.crayonColors objectForKey:crayon];
else
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];*/
```

Then I get no error whatsoever and it all scrolls just fine.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:

Here is the full Log of when I try to run the app and the error it gives when it crashes:

> [Session started at 2010-12-29 04:23:38 -0500.]
>
> [Session started at 2010-12-29 04:23:44 -0500.]
>   GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-967) (Tue Jul 14 02:11:58 UTC 2009)
>   Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
>   Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
>   There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   Attaching to process 1429.
>   gdb-i386-apple-darwin(1430,0x778720) malloc: *** mmap(size=1420296192) failed (error code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
>   [ 0 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (align_down+0x0) [0x1222d8]
>   [ 1 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (xstrvprintf+0x0) [0x12336c]
>   [ 2 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (xmalloc+0x28) [0x12358f]
>   [ 3 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (dyld_info_read_raw_data+0x50) [0x1659af]
>   [ 4 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (dyld_info_read+0x1bc) [0x168a58]
>   [ 5 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (macosx_dyld_update+0xbf) [0x168c9c]
>   [ 6 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (macosx_solib_add+0x36b) [0x169fcc]
>   [ 7 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (macosx_child_attach+0x478) [0x17dd11]
>   [ 8 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (attach_command+0x5d) [0x64ec5]
>   [ 9 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (mi_cmd_target_attach+0x4c) [0x15dbd]
>   [ 10 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (captured_mi_execute_command+0x16d) [0x17427]
>   [ 11 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (catch_exception+0x41) [0x7a99a]
>   [ 12 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin (mi_execute_command+0xa9) [0x16f63]
>   /SourceCache/gdb/gdb-967/src/gdb/utils.c:1144: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 1420296192 bytes.
>   A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
>   further debugging may prove unreliable.
>
> The Debugger has exited with status 1.The Debugger has exited with status 1.

---

Here is the backtrace that I get when I set the breakpoint for malloc_error_break:

```
#0  0x0097a68c in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x01785bef in -[UILabel setText:] ()
#2  0x000030e0 in -[TableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x421d760, _cmd=0x29cfad8, aTableView=0x4819600, indexPath=0x42190f0) at /Volumes/Main2/Enayet/TableViewController.m:99
#3  0x016cee0c in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] ()
#4  0x016c6a43 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] ()
#5  0x016d954f in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow] ()
#6  0x016d08ff in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
#7  0x03e672b0 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#8  0x03e6706f in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#9  0x03e668c6 in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#10 0x03e6653a in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#11 0x03e6e838 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#12 0x00b00252 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#13 0x00aff65f in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x00afec48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x00156615 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x001566da in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x01689faf in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x00002398 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffefb0) at /Volumes/Main2/Enayet/main.m:14
```

### --------

---

Here is my complete source for the UITableViewController class:

```
//
//  TableViewController.m
//  Enayet
//
//  Created by Filip on 12/27/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "EnayetAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize crayonColors;
@synthesize filteredArray;
@synthesize sectionArray;
@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize searchDC;

- (TableViewController*) initToCall:(NSMutableDictionary*) toUseArray
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    crayonColors = toUseArray;
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
{ 
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) return 26;
    return 1; 
}

// Via Jack Lucky
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchBar setText:@""]; 
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) 
    {
        if ([[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section] count] == 0)
            return nil;
        //return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[ALPHA substringFromIndex:section] substringToIndex:1]];
        return [[ALPHA substringFromIndex:section] substringToIndex:1];
    }
    else return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Normal table
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) return [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section] count];

    // Search table
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    self.filteredArray = [self.crayonColors.allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return self.filteredArray.count;
}

// Convert a 6-character hex color to a UIColor object
- (UIColor *) getColor: (NSString *) hexColor
{
    unsigned int red, green, blue;
    NSRange range;
    range.length = 2;

    range.location = 0; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&red];
    range.location = 2; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&green];
    range.location = 4; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&blue];   

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)(red/255.0f) green:(float)(green/255.0f) blue:(float)(blue/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeue or create a cell
    UITableViewCellStyle style =  UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BaseCell"];
    if (!cell) cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:@"BaseCell"] autorelease];

    NSString* crayon;

    // Retrieve the crayon and its color
    if (aTableView == self.tableView)
    {
        Term *term = (Term *) [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        crayon = [term name];
    }
    else
    {
        crayon = [FILTEREDKEYS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = crayon;

    if (![crayon hasPrefix:@"White"])
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [self.crayonColors objectForKey:crayon];
    else
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}

// Grouped Tables do not support section indices (even though they kind of do)

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
{
    if (aTableView == self.tableView)  // regular table
    {
        NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
            if ([[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:i] count])
                [indices addObject:[[ALPHA substringFromIndex:i] substringToIndex:1]];
        // [indices addObject:@"\ue057"]; // <-- using emoji
        return indices;
    }
    else return nil; // search table
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (title == UITableViewIndexSearch) return 0;
    return [ALPHA rangeOfString:title].location;
 }

- (void)goToTwo:(Term*) toGive
{
    EnayetAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate setTerm:toGive];
    [appDelegate displayView:2];
}

// Respond to user selections by updating tint colors
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (aTableView == self.tableView)
    {
        [self goToTwo:[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    // Prepare the crayon color dictionary
    NSString *pathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"crayons" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"/"];
    NSArray *rawCrayons = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathname encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    self.crayonColors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    self.sectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) [self.sectionArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    for (NSString *string in rawCrayons) 
    {
        [self.crayonColors setObject:CRAYON_COLOR(string) forKey:CRAYON_NAME(string)];
        NSUInteger firstLetter = [ALPHA rangeOfString:[string substringToIndex:1]].location;
        if (firstLetter != NSNotFound) [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:[[Term alloc] initToCall:CRAYON_NAME(string)]];
    }
    //NSLog(@"%@", sectionArray);

    // Create a search bar
    self.searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)] autorelease];
    self.searchBar.tintColor = COOKBOOK_PURPLE_COLOR;
    self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    self.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    // Create the search display controller
    self.searchDC = [[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self] autorelease];
    self.searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;
}
@end
```

### ------

---

Here is my Term.m file:

```
//
//  Term.m
//  Enayet
//
//  Created by Filip on 12/27/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Term.h"


@implementation Term

@synthesize name;

- (Term*)initToCall:(NSString*) toSetName
{
    name = toSetName;
    return self;
}

- (NSString*)getName
{
    return name;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/
has a pretty great rundown on objective-c memory management. that said, I don't think anything there will fix your problem...

Comment: @Flipper: Can you edit your post to show the actual error message you get with the crash as well?

Comment: @Flipper: If it is alright, can we see the *getName* method?

Comment: Apple's own [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) are nicely concise.

Comment: I added my getName method into my original post.  Please tell me whatever else I should provide.

Comment: @Flipper: What do you see if you add this line directly under where you set crayon: NSLog(@"value of crayon: %@", crayon); does the app print something reasonable or does it crash there now when scrolling?

Comment: @Flipper: You sure the *getName* method returns a string?

Comment: @Jason Coco, The app prints out the values when it first loads.  But when I scroll then it doesn't print out anything extra and crashes.

Comment: @Simon, what else could the *getName* method return?

Comment: @Flipper: I guess it may return *nil*, if you haven't initialized it yet.

Comment: So that's your answer. Your crayon's name is overreleased. Can you post the whole code for your Term.m file? I'm betting in your initToCall: method on Term, you're directly assigning name to the parameter instead of copying or retaining it, right? So your app works within the scope of viewDidLoad: but not after. It's just magic coincidence that the garbage there gets objc_msgSend to call what looks like mmap with some garbage file data.

Comment: @Jason Coco, I have posted my Term.m source above.  Based on your response I think the problem may be in initToCall, just no idea what is exactly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `initToCall:` method, replace:

```
name = toSetName;
```

with:

```
name = [toSetName retain];
```

Even tho you set the property as a "retain" property, your original value is not retained because you assign it directly. In Cocoa terms, you never "take ownership" of it. Since the string value you were passed in is not owned by you, it ends up going away on you, and that is why you see the crash. If you assign ivars directly in the init methods, you have to remember to retain or copy them yourself. Your other option is to use the accessors:

```
self.name = toSetName;
```

In that case, you will automatically invoke your synthesized setter, which will retain the property for you (since you specified it as a "retain" property).

**EDIT:** Also, while not directly related to your issue here, it's good form to always invoke your superclass's designated initializer from your own designated initializer. So, the general pattern would be:

```
- (id)initToCall:(NSString*)toSetName
{
  if( (self = [super init]) ) { // call NSObject's designated initializer
    // do our initialization
    name = [toSetName retain]; // take ownership of this string
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added that and it is working just fine.  I have another question related to my code, I am having a gap appear at the top between the status bar and the search bar...and I cannot seem to find why that is caused.  Any ideas?  (Should I create a second question for that?)

Comment: @Jason Coco: Hmm.. That was a great bug hunt :) +1

Comment: @Flipper: Yes, definitely create a new question for that :) it will be more helpful to others who have that issue and are searching for it in the future.

Comment: Heh -- I do all the work and Jason takes home the gold. :)  (J/k -- I was about to write that your Term class is wrong when I saw Jason's response).

Comment: @bbum: Ha Bill! I was following the same line as well, I was just making comments on the original question since your answer/tutorial/debugging session was so well written :) I did upvote that last night tho!

Comment: @bbum, you were a great help too.  I wish I could vote up responses, but am not a high enough reputation for that.

Comment: @Flipper: You can't upvote answers even in your own question? I thought that you could...

Comment: No worries -- I'm just glad that another developer has achieved success!

Comment: @Jason Coco, No sadly I cannot.  It's really sad.

Comment: @bbum, I actually have another memory management problem and am posting a new question about that.  You have a chance there. ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, if there is a crash, there is a backtrace.  Post it.  Saw your edit;  set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` and post the backtrace.   Usually, such a malloc() failure indicates that you've either exhausted your 32 bit address space *or* you have caused a bogon value to be passed to malloc.

Secondly, if you have a memory management issue, Instruments can help you track it down.  Run your app using the Allocations instrument and try scrolling.  It should be quite apparent what is being allocated either so frequently to cause such a crash.

You said:

> The problem seems to be the part of
>   where crayon is being set and getName
>   is being called.

If the problem has to do with `getName`, then please post the code for `getName`.   As it is, there isn't anything in that code that seems obviously overly memory consuming.

The `getName` method looks fantastically straightforward. :)

---

In the debugger console, if you type `b malloc_error_break`, it'll set the breakpoint.  Or you can set the breakpoint as a "symbolic breakpoint" in Xcode's debugger window.

Instruments is a different tool;  you can "Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> Allocations" to run your app under instruments.

However, given the entirely bogus value being passed to malloc(), I suspect something else has gone wrong.

---

That backtrace is actually quite useful.   It indicates that the malloc() error is happening when the Cell is trying to allocate something related to setting the text.

**And** you also said that if you add `cell.textLabel.text = @"test";` then the error stops happening.

My best guess;  you are either over-releasing or corrupting the string that is supposed to be the rendered as the text of `cell.textLabel`.

In particular, I'd bet that `crayon` is over-released or corrupt in certain circumstances.  Try adding an `NSLog(@"crayon %@", crayon);` in your code and see if it barfs, too.  And, as someone suggested, try running with Zombie detection enabled (Run -> Run with Performance Tools -> Zombie Detection;  or whatever it is called).

Comment: I honestly do not know how to use the instruments all to well.  Where is the malloc_error_break and the backtrace stuff?   I did add my getName method in my original post.

Comment: I figured out how to add the symbolic breakpoint for malloc_error_break and when I press Continue I get this:  Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: Don't continue;  get the backtrace when the breakpoint is hit and post that!

Comment: I just figured that out and edited my original post to also include that.  I'm slowly learning.

Comment: No worries -- it is a lot to take in all at once.   This kind of problem is often difficult to solve even with years of experience.

Comment: I just ran the Performance Instrument and when I launch the app the resources are extremely high even before scrolling.  Like the bar is near the top at the start.

Comment: It will be;  the vertical axis scales with usage.

Comment: I can post my entire code of the UIViewTableController if you would like to see how I am setting the sectionArray?

Comment: @bbum, the vertical axis stays up really high near the top and doesn't move.

Comment: The real question is how are the contents of the arrays from which `crayon`'s value managed....

Comment: What do you mean by managed?  (I added my complete source in my original post; hopefully that helps.  The array is set at the bottom in viewDidLoad.)

Comment: "Managed" as in "life cycle of the object".  As several have suggested, print out the crayon in before you set the text of the cell.  I still suspect string corruption or mis-management of an NSString instance.

Comment: Here is my comment from above:  The app prints out the values when it first loads. But when I scroll then it doesn't print out anything extra and crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Total aside -- not the direct cause of your crash, but indicative of a pattern of use that is alien to standard iOS patterns.

You say you have:

```
- (NSString*)getName
{
    return name;
}
```

And:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

This is just wrong;  there is no need to define a `getName` method if you have defined a property for `name`.  Just use the `name` method, either via direct invocation or via dot syntax.

That is, this:

```
crayon = [[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getName];
```

Should be:

```
crayon = [[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
```

Comment: Hmmm...so does that method take up more memory/speed than it should?  I guess I am just so used to languages like Java where variables are normally set to private and accessor methods are set.  (I ran the app with your way just to test and still same problem, I didn't expect anything different though.)

Comment: Nope -- that is why I added it as a separate answer.  It doesn't take any significant resources, it is just wrong from a "standard patterns" perspective and completely unnecessary.   @property defines both a getter and setter.  There is no concept of public/private methods in Objective-C.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now.  That's going to take some getting used to, but I'll be sure to follow that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Your getName method is wrong. It needs to return an object with a retain count of +0 (retained and autoreleased in the caller's autorelease context).

```
-(NSString *)getName
{
  return [[name retain] autorelease];
}
```

As others have said, using @synthesize name to create the -(NSString *)name method and calling that instead is a better idea.

The bug triggering the failure you observed is almost-certainly in the code where name is set; I suspect you have not retained the value correctly.  Again if you use @synthesize name and call the generated -(void)setName:(NSString *) method to set the name it will work correctly.