# Using NSPredicate in 2D Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nspredicate, multidimensional-array

This question is based off of the same app/source from my previous question which can be found here:

[How to manage memory using classes in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552783/how-to-manage-memory-using-classes-in-objective-c)

I have a nested array which looks something like this when printed out (I only copied and pasted a brief part of it).

```
(
        (
        <Term: 0x4256420>,
        <Term: 0x420fa40>,
        <Term: 0x4257bd0>,
        <Term: 0x4257cf0>,
        <Term: 0x4257d90>,
        <Term: 0x4257e30>
    ),
        (
        <Term: 0x4257e50>,
        <Term: 0x4257f90>,
        <Term: 0x4257fb0>,
        <Term: 0x42580e0>,
        <Term: 0x4258170>,
        <Term: 0x4258210>,
        <Term: 0x4258230>,
        <Term: 0x4258360>,
        <Term: 0x4258400>,
        <Term: 0x42584a0>,
        <Term: 0x4258540>,
        <Term: 0x42585e0>,
        <Term: 0x4258670>,
        <Term: 0x4258710>
    ),
```

And here is my code for the search part of my table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Normal table
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) return [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section] count];

    // Search table
    //NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    //self.filteredArray = [self.crayonColors filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    self.filteredArray = [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


    return self.filteredArray.count;
}
```

I am getting the error that I cannot allocate enough room which means that I must be doing something wrong, I just cannot figure out what.

The commented out portion of the search part in the above method works but crayonColors is just a simple NSMutableDictionary of NSStrings and does not have arrays nested inside of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably, a `Term` object has a `name` property.  My question is "what are you trying to achieve?"  You have an array of arrays of objects, but what are you trying to get out of it?  (ie, what objects are you wanting to end up with?)

Comment: So sectionArray has that nested array of Term objects.  Using NSPredicate I am trying to search for whatever the person typed in the search bar.  So that means like if they type in 'A' I want whatever contains an 'A' in it.  I am trying to get those Term objects into the filteredArray.

Comment: but do you want them in a single array, or do you want an array of filtered arrays?  Or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do this with a single predicate.  However, you can do it with a key-path operator and a predicate in two separate calls.

So, you have an array of arrays of terms.  You want a single array of terms where its name contains 'A' (for example).  Here's what you do:

```
NSArray * allTerms = ...; //your array of arrays of terms
NSArray * collapsedTerms = [allTerms valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];

NSPredicate * filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"A"];
NSArray * filteredTerms = [collapsedTerms filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

The magic here is the `valueForKeyPath:` bit.  The [`@unionOfArrays` operator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178611) takes an array of arrays of objects, and returns an array of objects.  Here's what it's doing:  The `NSArray` is going to break the keypath up by `.`, giving it `@unionOfArrays` and `self`.  It's going to recurse and invoke `valueForKeyPath:` on itself using the second bit (self), and it's going to get back an array of arrays.  It's then going to mash all those arrays together into a single array, ignoring duplicates.  (If you want to remove duplicates, use `@distinctUnionOfArrays` instead)

Once we have that array of objects, we can then filter it normally using a simple `name CONTAINS 'blah'` predicate.

(I thought I might be able to get this to work using a `SUBQUERY`, but that's a strange beast and nothing was immediately obvious to me.)

For the super intrepid, you could do this with a single method call using KickingBear's collection extensions ([available here](http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/9)), but I would strongly advise against using hacks like that in a production setting. :)

Comment: A side note: if your arrays contain dictionaries you will need to change the keypath to `@unionOfArrays.@self` because in the original keypath `@unionOfArrays.self`, the `self` part is interpreted as a key to retrieve objects from your dictionaries...

Comment: @albertamg Thanks for the tip with dictionaries! You saved me an hour of head-scratching.

Comment: @albertamg & Dave Delong you guys have saved me a ton of time. Thanks much!