# Using NSPredicate to filter array of arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have the following situation:

```
NSArray(
    NSArray(
        string1,
        string2,
        string3,
        string4,
        string5,
    )
    ,
    NSArray(
        string6,
        string7,
        string8,
        string9,
        string10,
   )
)
```

Now I need a predicate that returns the array that contains a specific string.
e.g. Filter Array that contains string9 -> I should get back the entire second array because I need to process the other strings inside that array. Any ideas?

Comment: have look at it and do reply if usefull or any quetions [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559427/using-nspredicate-in-2d-arrays)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just for completeness: It *can* be done using `predicateWithFormat:`:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @[@"A", @"B", @"C"],
    @[@"D", @"E", @"F"],
];

NSString *searchTerm = @"E";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", searchTerm];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

Output:

```
(
    (
        D,
        E,
        F
    )
)
```

Comment: +1, I was working on this with SUBQUERY, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF, $content, $content == [c] %@)",string]` but this didn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: @Anupdas: You were almost there, `@"SUBQUERY(SELF, $content, $content == [c] %@).@count > 0"` works.

Comment: @MartinR Awesome, it works. So the result of the subquery should be equated to some for even forming the predicate. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anupdas: Exactly, the SUBQUERY returns a *set*, but the predicate must evaluate to true or false.

Comment: is it possible to get only  E as element of nested array

Answer (score 1):

From what I know you can't do it as a one-liner so instead of using `predicateWithFormat:` you should use `predicateWithBlock:`

Something like this should do what you want

```
NSString *someString = @"Find me"; // The string you need to find.
NSArray *arrayWithArrayOfStrings = @[]; // Your array
[arrayWithArrayOfStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSArray *evaluatedArray, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedArray indexOfObject:someString] != NSNotFound;
 }]];
```

**Update:**
Martin R proved me wrong :)